# Find$\frac{dz}{dx} \text{for} \ z = \frac{xy}{x^2+ y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find $\frac{dz}{dx}$ for

$$  z =  \frac{xy}{x^2+ y^2}. $$

That means that $y$ must be constant and I should find the derivative. So,

$$\cfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\mapsto  \cfrac{y(y^2-x^2)}{(y^2+x^2)^2}$$ right? The answer in my book is $\cfrac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: I also find your answer right. Maybe you misanderstood the question and it asks for something else?

Comment: If you mean find $\dfrac{dz}{dx}$ where $z=\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, then "Find $\dfrac{dz}{dx}$ of $\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$" is a clumsy way to express it.

Comment: Troll... maybe?

Comment: @dsfdsf I'm hiding in Canada. How did you know I was a frog? Seriously, you should learn how to edit your questions/answers with appropriate TeX.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with your claim that ${dz\over dx}$ means hold $y$ constant. You may be thinking of ${\partial z\over\partial x}$, in this you hold $y$ constant. I believe the interpretation of ${dz\over dx}$ is an implicit assuption that $z$ is a function of $x$ only. That is, we assume there is some relation $y(x)$, and so $z(x)=z(x,y(x))$. Strictly speaking, I think it is good form to rename it, for instance $\tilde z(x)=z(x,y(x))$. Are you sure the problem does not state that we restrict to some curve $y(x)$?

For then, I would write:

$${d\tilde z\over dx}={d\over dx}z(x,y(x))={\partial z\over\partial x}+{\partial z\over\partial y}{dy\over dx}.$$